# C# console window won't show up

Tags: c#

I am trying to run a "Hello World" application in C# but when I run the program a console window does not show up.

I have made sure that I have started a console application first of all and I have made sure under Options>Run>General tab that "Run on external console" is checked. So I can't for the life of me figure out why the window will not appear.

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld3
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
            Console.ReadLine ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Press F5 and tell me what you see.

Comment: Is the project a Console Application?

Comment: @VisualVincent Of course, if it is just a Class Library (the other main default OP might have missed), it would say "Cannot start a project of type Class Library."

Comment: Do you have multiple projects in your solution? If so, is this the start up project?

Comment: @krillgar : He could've chosen another project type, there are many of them that are runnable. He could _for example_ have chosen WinForms and removed the form and/or changed some project settings. The Program.cs file still contains the main.

Comment: @VisualVincent Correct.  If the user did that, they would not see anything happen.  See Properties - Application - Output Type.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first line and debug (F5). Also, in the project's properties, the Application tab, what does "Output type" have?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code. It's either that the window get behind something or that you're not executing it (although thinking that you do).

Is VS orange at the bottom while running? Can you see any window indicators appearing in the task bar?

Your problem seems to be with your specific configuration. Are you sure there's no compile errors?

Comment: Sorry what does VS mean? again bear with me I am very new to this....I'm hitting the little sideways triangle (play button) in the top right or clicking the "run" tab and "start debugging" to run the program. Is this correct?

Comment: also, I don't see any window indicators when i run the program. I alt+tab and don't see any console window hiding that way either.

Comment: definitely no compile errors. After i run it, it says build successful in the top middle bar.

Comment: VS = Visual Studio. Don't worry. We've all been new to this stuff once. I wonder what happens if you execute the binary by double-clicking it instead of debug running it from the editor. Right-mouse on the project to open the folder of it. Then, go into bin and Debug and there it should be.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure the window just isn't popping up and dropping off really fast? Try adding Console.ReadKey() after Console.Writeline() to pause the window and wait for user input.

Comment: In the fourth line from the bottom of his code you can see that he already uses `Console.ReadLine()`.

Comment: Mine is using ReadyKey to invoke user input as a test, not ReadLine.

Comment: `ReadLine()` also invokes user input, what the user has written until ENTER is pressed! _Both the `ReadKey` and `ReadLine` functions are blocking in the exact same way!_

Comment: It's just another test :)

Comment: It is, but I'm afraid it won't be the solution to his problem.

Comment: ReadKey and ReadLine don't block the same way though. Sure, both of them block requiring user input, but in a different context. ReadKey locks Console.InternalSyncObject to halt console activity. ReadLine doesn't block the thread with that behavior.